# Why was this question about coefficients in Big O notation upvoted instead of being closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, scope, upvotes

I saw that this question had received many upvotes and was not closed:

[Why do we ignore co-efficients in Big O notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954109/why-do-we-ignore-co-efficients-in-big-o-notation)

I was confused by this, because it seems to me that the question is not about programming and therefore is off-topic here. Is this considered a good, on-topic question for Stack Overflow? If not, why was it upvoted instead of being closed?

Comment: There is no point in speculating on that. And it doesn't seem to be off-topic either.

Comment: @oguzismail I don't see how it is not off-topic because that question is not about programming

Comment: @oguzismail It seems that I misunderstood what topics are on-topic.... I thought that only programming questions are valid here

Comment: That *is* a programming question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to make an assumption about the reason behind your misunderstanding. We experience daily a flood of *do my job for me* questions, that often don't show any attempt to solve the issue.

In other words, these are questions that don't contain **code**.

Altough it is correct to close those questions, these leads to a common mistake: thinking that *every* question without code deserves to be closed. It is wrong: a lot of popular *howto* high rated questions don't have any code in them.

So, when you write

> the question is not about programming and therefore is off-topic here

you probably meant

> the question doesn't contain code

But actually *questions with code* are a subset of *programming questions*, so do exist programming questions that don't need code snippets. General questions about big-O notation belong to that set, and are on-topic on this site.

Comment: How exactly are you defining "do my job for me" questions? It seems to have a lot of overlap with "how to" questions. Since you're claiming that one should be closed, but not the other, could you clarify that a bit?

Comment: @cigien well, I'd probably never open a question without code, in order to "protect" my question from closure. But it is something really common for universal tasks such as "how to read a text file in C?". I'm not sure, maybe in some old questions the code attempt was removed later. What I agree with is that, for such universally useful question (the _mission_ of SO) the wrong attempt is just clutter.

Comment: Ah, I see. So it seems to me that by "do my job for me" questions you're talking about requests for code that are too broad, which I agree should be closed. Is that correct? Because questions that are focused don't need an attempt, and as you point out, a faulty attempt just clutters up the question.

Answer (score 22):

Despite popular belief we're not just a *debug this code for me* site.

Sometimes questions get asked that have to do about the understanding of the complexity of our code. That is a practical programming problem.

The understanding how the theory around Big-O gets applied/used in real life/code is a useful question for programmers.

Useful questions get upvotes.